# CakePHP Table intermediate and ordinary table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, foreign-key-relationship

I'm a beginner in CakePHP and I need your help on tables. What is the difference between this relationship tables:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  category_id int(11) NOT NULL,  
  producer_id int(11) NOT NULL,  
  name varchar(25) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  description text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY name (name)
);

CREATE TABLE categories (
  id int(11)NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(45) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  description varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY name (name)
);


CREATE TABLE producers(
  id int(11)NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and the intermediate

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
  id int(11)NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(45) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  description varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY name (name)
);

CREATE TABLE producers(
  id int(11)NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE category_producers(
  id int(11)NOT NULL auto_increment,  
  category_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  producer_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE products (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  category_producer_id int(11) NOT NULL,  
  name varchar(25) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  description text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  timestamp timestamp(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY name (name)
);
```

What is the fundamental difference? Which to use? And how is the CRUD operation for an intermediate table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fundamental difference**

The purpose of the category_producers table to store the many-to-many relationship between categories and producers.

In the first design, a product can have any combination of producer and category.
In the second design, the category_producers table stores all valid combinations of producers and categories.

As an example:

**Categories**

```
Electronics
Vehicles
```

**Producers**

```
Sony
Toyota
Mitsubishi
```

With the first design, you could make a product that is a Vehicle category produced by Sony.
With the second design, you would populate the category_producers table with valid combinations.

For example

```
Electronics  Sony
Vehicles     Toyota
Vehicles     Mitsubishi
Electronics  Mitsubishi
```

which would not allow a product with a Vehicle category produced by Sony.

**Which to use**

That is your decision based on ***your*** business requirements.

**CRUD operations**

You need to read how [cakephp handles relations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html), specifically the [hasAndBelongsToMany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm).